# How to set an image as a background in div?

Tags: html, css, django

How can I insert an image into url():

```html
<div class="panel active" style="background-image: url();">
  <h3>Business Session</h3>
</div>
```

I tried template tag with this {% load static %} and also absolute path but it does not work.

My image is in the static directory.

It works:

```
<div class="panel active" style="background-image: url('{% static 'home/daniel.jpg' %}')">
        <h3>Business Session</h3>
      </div>
```

But VS code highlights part of the template tag in red. Is it a good practice to do that?
[image]

Comment: Please include *code*, not *images of code*: see [*Why not upload images of code errors when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). [edit] the question and include code fragments with the *code sample* button (`{}`).

Answer (score 1):

Try It Like That:

`<div class="panel active" style="background: url(/static/home/daniel.jpg)"> <h3>Business Session</h3> </div>`